# How to create a container within a python script?

Tags: python, kivy, containers

Within my cross-platform Kivy python app I would like to include a container to execute untrusted code. How can a container be implemented via python?

I've tried researching this but haven't found anything. Is it even possible?

- Docker and Podman won't work because I need this to be a standalone app
- Buildah won't work because it's only for linux

Comment: What do you mean by standalone app? That it only requires python?

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez Standalone as in no external apps are needed for it to work. From my understanding Docker requires you to have the Docker app in order to use their containers and there's no way to package it within my app so my users can just download my app and use it without needing to install Docker.

Comment: What exactly is the untrusted code? Is it only python, or is it an arbitrary executable?

Comment: @Command-Alt-Escape it would be bash scripts that our users write themselves or share amongst the community (and they could be sharing malicious scripts)

Comment: I don't think there is a safe way to do this for bash scripts, at least without requiring root/admin privileges when installing. The only way I could think of is by running a docker container on a remote server, executing the scripts on that server, and sending the result back to the client. If python scripts are fine, [PyPy has a sandboxing feature](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html) that might work for you.